# Creating where condition for LINQ within switch statement

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

So basically I have to get 4 different List of employees for 4 different roles. `List of Roles` is a `List of Enum` as below:

```
public enum Roles {
       [Description("Level 1")]
       L1,

       [Description("Level 2")]
       L2,

       [Description("Level 3")]
       L3,

       [Description("Level 4")]
       L4
};
```

- `L1` can view `L1`,`L2`,`L3` and `L4`
- `L2` can view `L2`,`L3` and `L4`
- `L3` can view `L3` and `L4`.
- `L4` do not have permission to view any of employee.

Now below is how I have written query for fetching employees.

```
if (!Equals(Role, Enum.GetName(typeof(GlobalMethods.Roles), 3)))
{
      var _role = (GlobalMethods.Roles)Enum.Parse(typeof(GlobalMethods.Roles), Role,true);
      List<EmployeeViewModel> employees = new List<EmployeeViewModel>();
      switch (_role)
      {
            case GlobalMethods.Roles.L1:
                 employees = context.tblEmployees.Where(x => x.EmpID != homeViewModel.UserViewModel.EmpID).ToList().Select(x => new EmployeeViewModel
                 {
                      EmpActive = x.EmpActive,
                      EmpDOB = x.EmpDOB,
                      EmpName = x.EmpName
                 }).ToList();
                 break;
            case GlobalMethods.Roles.L2:
                 employees= context.tblEmployees.Where(x => x.EmpID != homeViewModel.UserViewModel.EmpID).ToList().Where(x=>x.EmpRole != Enum.GetName(typeof(GlobalMethods.Roles), 0)).Select(x => new EmployeeViewModel
                 {
                      EmpActive = x.EmpActive,
                      EmpDOB = x.EmpDOB,
                      EmpName = x.EmpName,
                 }).ToList();
                 break;
            case GlobalMethods.Roles.L3:
                 employees = context.tblEmployees.Where(x => x.EmpID != homeViewModel.UserViewModel.EmpID).ToList().Where(x.EmpRole != Enum.GetName(typeof(GlobalMethods.Roles), 0) && x.EmpRole != Enum.GetName(typeof(GlobalMethods.Roles), 1)).Select(x => new EmployeeViewModel
                 {
                      EmpActive = x.EmpActive,
                      EmpDOB = x.EmpDOB,
                      EmpName = x.EmpName,
                 }).ToList();
                 break;
            default: break;
      }
}
```

So in the above code I have the same LINQ query but only the `where` condition differs. Is there any way I can prepare a dynamic `where` condition and fetch the list once for all?

Comment: Shall be feasible by creating an `Expression tree` (Binary Expression) and combining them using `And` to ensure the final result

Comment: I think, I over-understood your requirements, to suggest a generic solution based on Expression trees, nonetheless that does provide good amount of flexibility to the overall solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. It makes the assumption that each **GlobalMethods.Roles** can view all roles with a greater int values. That is the case for the roles are rules that you have stated.

```
if (!Equals(Role, Enum.GetName(typeof(GlobalMethods.Roles), 3)))
{
     var _role = (GlobalMethods.Roles)Enum.Parse(typeof(GlobalMethods.Roles), Role, true);
     List<EmployeeViewModel> employees = new List<EmployeeViewModel>();
     string[] viewableRoles = GetViewableRoles(_role);
     employees = context.tblEmployees
                .Where(x => x.EmpID != homeViewModel.UserViewModel.EmpID && viewableRoles.Contains(x.EmpRole))
                .Select(x => new EmployeeViewModel
                {
                    EmpActive = x.EmpActive,
                    EmpDOB = x.EmpDOB,
                    EmpName = x.EmpName
                }).ToList();
}

private string[] GetViewableRoles(GlobalMethods.Roles userRole)
{
    //Uncomment if L4 can actually view no roles, including itself.
    // /if (userRole == GlobalMethods.Roles.L4)
    // {
    //  return new string[0];
    // }

    IEnumerable<GlobalMethods.Roles> allRoles = Enum.GetValues(typeof(GlobalMethods.Roles)).Cast<GlobalMethods.Roles>();
    return (from role in allRoles 
                where (int)role >= (int)userRole 
                select role.ToString()).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful solution.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Kudos, for understanding the problem correct and providing a simple solution +1

Answer (score 1):

This is simplified but you can do something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person{ Name = "John" },
            new Person{ Name = "Amy" }
        };

        Func<Person, bool> pred = null;
        Roles role = Roles.RoleA;
        switch (role)
        {
            case Roles.RoleA:
                pred = p => p.Name.StartsWith("J");
                break;
            case Roles.RoleB:
                pred = p => p.Name.StartsWith("A") && p.Name.Length >= 3;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        var result = list.Where(pred);
    }
}

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

enum Roles
{
    RoleA,
    RoleB
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would like to go with accepted answer as it seems more easy and solution is onto the question. +1 for your effort.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Following is the generic Expression tree extension method, to take care of the following requirement (you certainly need to modify to suit your specific requirements)

- `T` is the final type of `IEnumerable`
- `T1` is the type of column for the filtering in the where clause
- Declare `ParameterExpression` for a given Type `T` outside extension method for reuse, while compiling `Expression Tree to Func`, though this can also be done separately in the `Extension method` and during `Func` generation

  `ParameterExpression parameterType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "object");`

  ```
  public static class CustomExpression
  {
   // Create Initial Expression Tree
   public static BinaryExpression InitialExpression<T,T1>(
                                                          ParameterExpression parameterType
                                                          string columnName,
                                                          T1 value)
  {
      // Optional can be taken outside the Extension method to create a Func<T,bool>

      //ParameterExpression parameterType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "object");

      MemberExpression typeColumn = Expression.Property(parameterType, columnName);

      ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(T1));

      return Expression.NotEqual(typeColumn, constant);
  }

  // Create Combined Expression Tree
  public static BinaryExpression CombinedExpression<T,T1>(this BinaryExpression mainExpression,
                                                          ParameterExpression parameterType
                                                          string columnName,
                                                          T1 value)
  {
      // Optional can be taken outside the Extension method to create a Func<T,bool>

      //ParameterExpression parameterType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "object");

      MemberExpression typeColumn = Expression.Property(parameterType, columnName);

      ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(T1));

      return Expression.And(mainExpression,Expression.NotEqual(typeColumn, constant));
  }
  }
  ```

Following is the Call Hierarchy in your case:

- Declare final binary expression for the `Linq` query:

  `BinaryExpression finalBinaryExpression = null;`

  ```
   switch (_role)
    {
          case GlobalMethods.Roles.L1:
            finalBinaryExpression =          
            CustomExpression.InitialExpression<EmployeeViewModel,int>     
            (parameterType,"EmpID",homeViewModel.UserViewModel.EmpID);
           break;
          case GlobalMethods.Roles.L2:
            finalBinaryExpression =     
            CustomExpression.InitialExpression<EmployeeViewModel,int>               
            (parameterType,"EmpID",homeViewModel.UserViewModel.EmpID)
            .CombinedExpression<EmployeeViewModel,Roles>                    
        (parameterType,"EmpRole",Enum.GetName(typeof(GlobalMethods.Roles), 0));
           break;
          case GlobalMethods.Roles.L3:
              finalBinaryExpression =       
              CustomExpression.InitialExpression<EmployeeViewModel,int>
              (parameterType,"EmpID",homeViewModel.UserViewModel.EmpID)
              .CombinedExpression<EmployeeViewModel,Roles>

        (parameterType,"EmpRole",Enum.GetName(typeof(GlobalMethods.Roles), 0))
              .CombinedExpression<EmployeeViewModel,Roles>  

        (parameterType,"EmpRole",Enum.GetName(typeof(GlobalMethods.Roles), 1));
           break;
      }
  ```
- Create a `genericFunc` by compiling the binary expression as follows

  ```
  Func<T, bool> filterFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                             (finalBinaryExpression, parameterType).Compile();
  ```
- Final Result Apply the `Func` created above

  ```
    var finalResult = context.tblEmployees.Where(o => filterFunc(o));
  ```

Comment: Idea here is to create a combined Expression Tree, which can combine all the filter requirements and get applied for the final resultset

Comment: Agree with you @Mrinal, this is very useful, but my requirement was simple and the accepted answer above gives what is required. +1 for your time and effort..  Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, please check the modified version, in case you use in the future, since earlier one would have lead to `Null reference exception`, we need to create Initial expression separately. I use the similar code for lot of dynamic filtering of the grids

Comment: Sure @Mrinal.. I thank you for your effort. Am definitely gonna use this in future.. Thank you so much once again.. :)